# Rank top two highest values and also get their column names

Tags: r

I am not sure whether this question is asked before or not but I have searched and didnt find the same

I have a dataset:

```
X24_TT  X35_FTT X55_FTT X80_FTT
0.09    0.87    0.89    0.15
0.94    0.12    0.09    0.92
0.89    0.11    0.86    0.08
0.12    0.8     0.15    0.18
0.08    0.09    0.15    0.88
```

I want to rank columns and get the top 2 highest values and their column names respectively in following manner:

```
X24_TT  X35_FTT X55_FTT X80_FTT Rank 1  Col1    Rank2   Col2
0.09    0.87    0.89    0.15    0.89    X55_FTT 0.87    X35_FTT
0.94    0.12    0.09    0.92    0.94    X24_TT  0.92    X80_FTT
0.89    0.11    0.86    0.08    0.89    X24_TT  0.86    X55_FTT
0.12    0.8     0.15    0.18    0.8     X35_FTT 0.18    X80_FTT
0.08    0.09    0.15    0.88    0.88    X80_FTT 0.15    X55_FTT
```

Kindly provide the dynamic answer as the number of columns are huge

Comment: What is your expected output as there are two columns Rank1 and Rank2

Comment: @akrun My expected output are Rank 1, Col 1, Rank2, Col2

Comment: Please update it in your post

Comment: `df$rank1 <- apply(df,1,max)`, you can figure out the rest

Comment: @akrun updated the same in my post

Comment: Are you sure you want this in this format? I don't see how you can use this data afterwards

Comment: @mtoto There are much better ways such as `max.col(df)` or `do.call(pmax, df)`. If it was up to me, I would completely remove `apply` function from base R - certainly won't recommend it to new users who have no idea what's matrix conversion or methods dispatching or classes (though `max.cols` have this issue to, but at-least it's vectorized).

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y=1:10)

step1 <- df %>% gather() %>% group_by(key) %>% arrange(desc(value)) %>%
  filter(row_number(key) < 3) %>% mutate(rown = row_number(key))

dcast(step1, key ~ rown, mean )
```

gets the top 2 values of each column.

as you mention in the comments, you want it in the original dataframe per row.

```
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, x = rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(10))

step1 <- df %>% gather(keep = -id) %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(desc(value)) %>%
  filter(row_number(id) < 3) %>% mutate(rown = row_number(id))

merge(merge(df,step1[step1$rown == 1,], by = "id")
      ,step1[step1$rown == 2,], by = "id")
```

Comment: I want to add them as columns in my dataset

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like this:

```
c <- ncol(df)
r <- t(apply(df,1, function(x) {
       a <- sort(x,partial=c-1)[c(c,c-1)];
       c(Rank1=a[1], Col1=names(df)[which(x==a[1])], Rank2=a[2], Col2=names(df)[which(x==a[2])])
}))
cbind(df, r)

  # X24_TT X35_FTT X55_FTT X80_FTT Rank1    Col1 Rank2    Col2
# 1   0.09    0.87    0.89    0.15  0.89 X55_FTT  0.87 X35_FTT
# 2   0.94    0.12    0.09    0.92  0.94  X24_TT  0.92 X80_FTT
# 3   0.89    0.11    0.86    0.08  0.89  X24_TT  0.86 X55_FTT
# 4   0.12    0.80    0.15    0.18   0.8 X35_FTT  0.18 X80_FTT
# 5   0.08    0.09    0.15    0.88  0.88 X80_FTT  0.15 X55_FTT
```

The `partial` argument of `sort` is beneficial here as it does not sort the whole vector.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(X24_TT = c(0.09, 0.94, 0.89, 0.12, 0.08), X35_FTT = c(0.87, 
0.12, 0.11, 0.8, 0.09), X55_FTT = c(0.89, 0.09, 0.86, 0.15, 0.15
), X80_FTT = c(0.15, 0.92, 0.08, 0.18, 0.88)), .Names = c("X24_TT", 
"X35_FTT", "X55_FTT", "X80_FTT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```